# Is there a way to make Pandas area chart with time axes on x not to overlap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I am trying to display a data frame of a time series with 2 columns. Here is an example of the data frame.

| index | Alive T-3 | Alive T-3 & T+3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/31/2018 | 100 | 80 |
| 12/31/2019 | 120 | 90 |
| 12/31/2020 | 130 | 95 |
| 12/31/2021 | 140 | 98 |
| 12/31/2022 | 150 | 100 |
| 12/31/2023 | 160 | 123 |

This is what I am using to plot the chart

`survived.plot.area(stacked=False)`

The problem I am running into is that I have 621 entries in my time series and the plot end ups looking like that. Is there a way to have it more sparse? I don't really need the whole time series on the axes. Even years would be enough.

[image: Chart]

Comment: Convert the index to `datetime` not strings

Comment: That Worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @It_is_Chris mentioned, the index should be a `datetime`.

`survived.index = pd.to_datetime(survived.index)` did the work

[image: Worked]